# Using json objects in duktape

Tags: javascript, c++, json, duktape

everybody. I've just integrated duktape in my c++ code so that I'm able to use javascript.

But the problem I can't solve right now : how to use **json objects in javascript**.

Assume I've got some javascript like

```
function hi(person) {
    print ('hi, ' + person.name );
}
```

And json object :

```
{
    'name' : 'duktape'
}
```

So now I need to call function hi with an argument of this json in my cpp code.

```
duk_eval_string(ctx, "function hi(person) {print ('hi, ' + person.name );}");
    duk_push_global_object(ctx);
    duk_get_prop_string(ctx, -1, "hi" ); // pushes function from loaded script to stack

    auto json = "{'name' : 'duktape' }";
    duk_push_string(ctx, json);
    duk_pcall(ctx, 1);
```

The output I get tells, that object is not correct

```
hi, undefined
```

Would like to head any suggestions on who should be done to get it working! Thank's for your time :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`duk_json_decode`](http://duktape.org/api.html#duk_json_decode):

```cpp
char *json = "{\"name\": \"duktape\"}";
duk_push_string(ctx, json);
duk_json_decode(ctx, -1);
duk_pcall(ctx, 1);
duk_pop_2(ctx);
```

Output:

```
hi, duktape
```

*Note that your original json is not valid, you need to use `"` as string delimiters instead of `'`.*

Depending on what you really needs, you could also create the object manually:

```
duk_idx_t obj_idx = duk_push_object(ctx);
duk_push_string(ctx, "duktape");
duk_put_prop_string(ctx, obj_idx, "name");
duk_pcall(ctx, 1);
duk_pop(ctx);
```